# Why I am not able to turn on location in browser for my JavaScript app?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, geolocation, google-maps

I have created an app with javascript that uses the current location and I have build the app on top of `SharePoint`. I am using the above code. If I run this app in Sharepoint I am not able to use the location, `Location Blocked to protect your privacy` I am not able to turn on location because it is readonly;
[image]

I cannot use the location even in my phone I am not able to turn on the location. Why sharepoint sites wont be able to use location?

Please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: LatLng,
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: map,
        title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
} else {
alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your SP over HTTPS. If you don't have a valid certificate, you can create and add a one self-signed to test.

If you want to test with HTTP, try running your SP over `localhost`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257756/chrome-notifications-not-working-permission-not-requested